# VS 2015 - Keeping IIS alive AFTER debugging?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

When debugging in VS, especially when the application relies on remote web services (in the solution), it automatically spools up hosts for those web services as well. By default, when stopping the debug process, it kills the IIS Express processes. Typically, in VS 2013, I would disable "Edit and Continue" at the project level, and that kept the IIS Express process alive even AFTER I stopped the debug process. Merely using Ctrl + F5 doesn't automatically spin up the web services consumed by the application.

Is there a way to do this in VS 2015? Either I need F5 to keep the IIS Express process alive after hitting "stop", or somehow get Ctrl + F5 to spin up host processes for related web services. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the 'real' IIS?
That's a real web server, that will keep running with or without debugging.
You can install it from 'Windows features'. It also has the benefit, that you can have the same settings as your production server, to minimize problems going live.

Comment: I could, but it would require constant extra steps to update all the applications to use different paths for each project I'm working on (and I can be working on anywhere up to 4 or 5 at a time). It's a bit more configuration, where IIS Express gets configured automatically.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, you can "detach" from the process instead of stopping it.

Debug [menu] -> Detach All